# An image from a video element displayed with artifacts in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to use a video tag to process video frames.

For some reason there are artifacts at the edge of the video when using Chrome. It looks like the video is smaller by about 14 pixels compared to the original and the rest is filled with a glitch:

[image]

Same code works perfectly fine in Firefox. The [original video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/test.mp4) file doesn't have artifacts when I play it with VLC, QuickTime, or WMP.

Here's the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="370" height="740" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<video id="test" width="0" height="0" >
   <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/test.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<script>
   window.onload = function() {

      var media = document.getElementById("test");
      media.onloadeddata = function() {
         var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.drawImage(media, 0, 0);
      }
      media.load();
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And [a link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gatoszye/) so you can try it yourself.

Am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug in Chrome, is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the browser hardware acceleration. Everything works fine as soon as I turn it off. See my other question: [HTML5 canvas clip() doesn't work in Chrome when rotation is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026145/html5-canvas-clip-doesnt-work-in-chrome-when-rotation-is-applied)

Comment: Didn't saw this question at the time, but you should definitely fill a bug to chrome with your config. Can not reproduce this one either ;-)