# HTML5 canvas clip() doesn't work in Chrome when rotation is applied

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use a clip region on a canvas and it stops working as soon as the coordinate system is rotated by any non zero value:

```js
   window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 8); // !!! Clipping doesn't work with any non zero value

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.clip(); // !!! Image below is invisible in Chrome when clip() is enabled
      
      var objectImage = document.getElementById("test");
      ctx.drawImage(objectImage, 0, 0);
   }
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="320" height="240" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<img id="test" width="0" height="0" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/test.png">
```

The code works fine in Firefox:

[image: Canvas in Firefox]

But in Chrome the image inside the rectangle is empty:

[image: Canvas in Chrome]

Translate and scale transformations seem to work fine, but not the rotate. Am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug in Chrome, is there a good workaround?

**Edit:**

My system is:
Chrome "Version 49.0.2623.87 m", Windows 7 Home Premium SP1, ASUS R7 250X graphics card. I can reproduce the problem every time.

I found that the problem goes away if I **turn off hardware acceleration** in the browser settings. As I understand this means there's probably a problem with my graphics card driver.

Is there a way for my webpage to force the software rendering in Chrome?

Comment: Works fine here. (Chrome 49, Mac OS X 10.9.5 )

Comment: @Kaiido I've added my system specs to the post.

Comment: I am having similar issue with the canvas control with that release of Chrome.  Like you it works if I turn off hardware acceleration but this is not good for my users and will not take advantage of the graphics card. I have posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175526/canvas-not-rendering-image-it-used-to?noredirect=1#comment59989234_36175526

Comment: Your code also works fine in chrome on my PC. If you only want to rotate the image ...then try without **ctx.clip()**

Comment: Works fine for me running Chrome v49.0.2623.108. Have you tried changing the order of operations? Clip outside the rectangle then rotate?

Comment: @mpactMEDIA and then how are you gonna have a rotated clip region ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the browser hardware acceleration. Everything works fine as soon as I turn it off.

[image: Hardware acceleration browser setting]

However, I don't know if it's possible for my web page to disable hardware acceleration.

Comment: I have been investigating a similar issue (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5305) and created a Chromium bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611022.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, drawImage() is done before Image loaded, you have to check like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script>
      window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 8); // !!! Clipping doesn't work with any non zero value
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.clip(); 
      
      //Make sure the Image is loaded
      var objectImage= new Image();
      objectImage.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/test.png"
      objectImage.onload =function()
      {
           ctx.drawImage(objectImage, 0, 0);
      }
   }
</script>
<body>
    <img id="test" width="0" height="0" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4111969/test.png">
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="320" height="240" style = "border:1px solid #d3d3d3; margin:0; padding:0"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.onload` will fire when all the content in html document has loaded, not the problem here, unless you were able to repro OP's issue and that it solves it ?