# Canvas not rendering image it used to

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an asp.net web app.

I use web sockets and HTML5/canvas to render images to my web page.

This is the JS for this:

```
function setUpImageProc() {
    desktopImage.onload = function () {
      ctxLiveViews.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0, 360, 240);
    }
}


var desktopImage = new Image;

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    desktopImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + arrayBufferToBase64(e.data);
};  

setUpImageProc();           


var canvasLiveViews = document.getElementById("canvasLiveView1");
ctxLiveViews = canvasLiveViews.getContext("2d");
canvasLiveViews.width = 360;
canvasLiveViews.height = 240;
```

Now this used to work.
It no longer works in Chrome
It works in Edge
If I disable the hardware acceleration it will work
If I use `<img>` instead of `<canvas>` it will work.

I am thinking this is due to an upgrade of the Chrome Browser but I am surprised that no one else has complained about this?

Is my above JS script correct or is badly set?

Additional Points:
There are no console messages

The onMessage handler definitely fires

I wrap the onLoad function because it is stored in an external file and I was having problems loading this script into my page.  By doing what I did seemed to solve this problem though I would have to post further code to demonstrate this.

I have tried loading the canvas directly rather that using the onLoad event

Comment: @Hacketo these were genuine copy and paste errors from my remote server.  I have amended these horrors now.  thanks for point these out. Obviously, needed more coffee!

Comment: On the off chance - have you checked that the image has finished loading before attempting to render it to the canvas? It may have been working in the past because the image was previously cached.

Comment: @Lewis Hi thanks for taking an interest. This bit of script 'desktopImage.onload ' does that.. but thanks :)

Comment: So it does, that'll teach me to make sure I fully read code before commenting! ^^

Comment: lol.  I do these sort of things many times myself

Comment: Is there any message in the console ? Are you sure the `onmessage` handler fires ?  why do you wrap the `onload` in a function, what happens if you do set it directly when the ImageObject is created ? What happens when you don't call `drawImage` out of the canvas boundaries  (`.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0, 360, 240);` instead of `260`) ? Does this only occurs when dealing with dataURI src or with any ? does this also occurs if you hardcode the arrayBuffer or only when sent by worker ?

Comment: @Kaiido thaking your good points in order:

Comment: I meant that instead of loading the desktop image and using its onload to render the image to my displayed canvas  I have set it directly to that canvas

Comment: @Kaiido You are most welcome to ask me questions.  it will eliminate the obvious and I welcome your input :)

Comment: No what I meant was to attach the event listener directly to the image when you created it : `var desktopImage = new Image; desktopImage.onload = function () {
      ctxLiveViews.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0, 360, 260); 
    }` Webkit browsers have some bugs related to event that fire before the end of the synchronous calls, so it's really unlikely here, but it may be an issue. and always better to set the onload right after you created the image, and before you set its src.

Comment: @Kaiido ah I see. i shall put that in now then - ta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107126/discussion-between-kaiido-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: @kaido I may be slow to respond as I am at work

Comment: Google have released Chrome update and it now works!